# Pass value from jquery variable to php variable

Tags: php, jquery, variables

I need to get id from table row by clicking on that row and use that id in another php file. For this I was getting id by jquery, the code is

`var id = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(0)').text();` // it's working

And I want to pass this id as php variable. But any one isn't work.
My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#people-table tr").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(0)').text();
     $.ajax({
        url: "default_people.php",
        type: "GET",

        data: { id1: id},
        success: function (result) {
                alert(id);
        }
    });
  });
});
```

And my php code is:

```
  $a = $_GET['id1'];
  echo $a ;
```

Comment: update alert(id) with alert(result);

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is already a `tr` element:

```
var id = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text(); // use this
```

so you don't have to traverse up to the `tr`* with `.closest()`, you can remove it.

and in the success function you are using a wrong argument:

```
success: function (result) {
     alert(result); // <-------update to this
}
```

and at `php` end you can use `isset()` method:

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
  $a = $_GET['id1'];
  echo $a ;
}
```

<sub>* depends on your dom structrue actually.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Try jquery `$.get` :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#people-table tr").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(0)').text();
     $.get("default_people.php?id="+id);
  });
});
```